# Can't Open a File Using Intent

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

What I am trying to do here is that. I locate the Pdf file folder in my SD Card and click the file and it complete action using Adobe Reader. I successfully done the read SD card option and it shows all pdf file in layout as a gridview. But when I click the pdf file it opens Adobe reader but can't open the file. It says "The document can't be opened because it's not a valid pdf doc". Here is my Code-

Here is the code for locating File & folder in SD card

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.magica_pdf_layout, container, false);

    // Check for SD Card
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(PdfFragment.this.getActivity(), "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } 

    else 
    {
        // Locate folder in your SD Card
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "Book");

        // Create a new folder if no folder named exist
        file.mkdirs();


    }
```

here is the part for onclick method

```
// Capture gridview item click
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {
            // get clicked file name from gridview
            String pdfname=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
             //prepare pdf file url
            selectedFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator +pdfname+".pdf");
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent();
            pdfIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(selectedFile), "application/pdf");
            startActivity(pdfIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: show how preparing `file` path?

Comment: file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "Book");
file.mkdirs();

Comment: please edit more code in post to understand issue

Comment: Book is a folder in SD card and read all the pdf file into the folder. It read all the pdf file and show as a gridview in an activity. When I click the pdf file adobe reader start but show message that pdf file not valid.

Comment: see my answer probably help

Answer (score 0):

> The document can't be opened because it's not a valid pdf doc

Because you are not passing pdf file path, currently passing only folder path in which all files are present. do it as:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                                 View view,int position, long id) 
    {
        // get clicked file name from gridview
         String pdfname=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        // prepare pdf file url
        File selectedFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+pdfname+".pdf");
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent();
        pdfIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(selectedFile), "application/pdf");
        startActivity(pdfIntent);
    }
```

Comment: sorry it couldn't help. As you can see I declear file path before 


file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "Book");

so I think I don't need to write 

File selectedFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+pdfname+".pdf");

again.

Comment: The URI object is referring to a folder (Book) instead of a PDF. Add the path to the PDF like prosper says. Also, ensure that the PDF is inside the Book directory.

Comment: I edit my source code again. when I run the application it closed.please give me a small brief about it. It will be helpful to me

Comment: @prospera Now application closed automatically. Look I edit my question add source code. It will be great if you help me to solve it.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(28897):  at com.tv.magica.pdf.PdfFragment$1.onItemClick(PdfFragment.java:113)
02-05 02:20:35.593: 
E/AndroidRuntime(28897):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
02-05 02:20:35.593: 
E/AndroidRuntime(28897):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1507)
02-05 02:20:35.593: 
E/AndroidRuntime(28897):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3292)
02-05 02:20:35.593:

Comment: pdfGridViewAdapter adapter;

Comment: What is line number 113 in PdfFragment.java ?

Comment: String pdfname=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);